# Implementing a Browse button in Flutter for Windows platform

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

I am building an application in flutter for Windows plateform. I want to select a folder from windows file browser upon clicking on a browse button. Please help what should I do to pop up a windows explorer from which I can select any folder. In simple words I want to add a BROWSE button in project.
[Picture: Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpKRn.jpg)

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Which plugin did you use?

Comment: No, I just not tried the desktop version after that

Answer (score 0):

The `file_chooser` [experimental FDE plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins) does exactly that as a temporary solution until Flutter itself supports it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [file_picker](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter/issues/205) plugin that works on Windows made by **chunhunghan**. But you should make your project to unofficial desktop version [go-flutter](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter). If you really want to keep the official project, just wait for *FDE* plugin to support It.

By the way, Develop plugin by `golang` is more easier than `c++` in this [post](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter/issues/191), so this project seems to be more easier for plugins to support cross-platform. For not too bias, just stop to talk here, and give It a try.

Comment: The way the Go file_picker plugin works is by calling a Go library that has a completely different implementation for every platform, calling into native platform UI libraries. In other words, it's exactly the same structure as a non-Go implementation, just using Go. There are certainly cases where Go would make implementing cross-platform plugins easier (most notably, wrapping libraries that are already cross-platform, like SQLite), but this is not one of them.